# Using font in google extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to create a simple google extension that replaces the newtab page with the index.html that I created. But the extension cannot display the font I use in the index.html file. When I deployed the index.html file, the font still worked perfectly. This is the code I use in the index.html file

```
<style>
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inconsolata:wght@500&display=swap');
    
    html {
      font: 22px/1 'Inconsolata', monospace !important;
    }
</style>
```

What did I do wrong, and how can I fix this?

Comment: Download the font and include it within the extension like any other local asset.

Comment: I think I found the error. When I move the font property to the body, it works.

Comment: Indeed, extensions internally set a default font on `body`.